# wix React-Native-Navigation V1 transparent background not working as expected

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to set the screen background to transparent using this navigator property:

`screenBackgroundColor: 'transparent'`

In addition, I changed the root view background color to Green in XCode like this:

`self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];`

I'm expecting to see the Green background without any interference . When running in Simulator I see a black rectangle with some opacity and a gradient toward the green color on the margins... (please see screenshot below) how to fix that? Maybe I'm missing some flag??

[black rectangle instead of green background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ZrH.png)

I'm also using these other navigator style properties:

`navBarTranslucent: true
navBarTransparent: true,
navBarNoBorder: true,
drawUnderNavBar: true
navBarTranslucent:true,
navBarBlur: false,`

here I try to set the NavBar to Red background color and it still not working:

[navbar background color red instead of transparent - still not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew9XD.png)

Comment: If you put your nav bar to a solid colour, does just the nav bar go to that colour? It looks as if a container view has the 'funky gradient' as it's covering the whole screen?

Comment: it just paints the nav bar (as an example) in red. the left of the window is still covered with the black rectangle and the funky gradients at the borders. you can see my original post for a screenshot showing the red navbar.

Comment: it seems to prove that the Nav bar isn't the issue here - rather the container view. Could you post your component code?